# Is there a way to make a TSQL variable constant?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to make a TSQL variable constant?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

No, but you can create a function and hardcode it in there and use that.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnConstant()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 2
END
GO

SELECT dbo.fnConstant()
```

Comment: `WITH SCHEMABINDING` **should** turn this into a 'real' constant (a requirement for a UDF to be seen as deterministic in SQL). I.e. it should land up being cached. Still, +1.

Comment: this answer is good, just curious can table columns in sqlserver reference a function as a default value. i could not get this to work

Comment: @JonathanDickinson To be clear, your suggestion is to use `WITH SCHEMABINDING` in the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement (as opposed to in a stored procedure that might be calling the function) -- is that right?

Comment: Yes, in the function. WITH SCHEMABINDING allows SQL to inline "inlined table-valued functions" - so it *also* needs to be in this form: https://gist.github.com/jcdickinson/61a38dedb84b35251da301b128535ceb. The query analyzer won't inline anything without SCHEMABINDING or anything with BEGIN.

Comment: Implications of using non deterministic UDFs: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/archive/blogs/sqlprogrammability/improving-query-plans-with-the-schemabinding-option-on-t-sql-udfs

Comment: I think the omission of schemabinding makes this answer deprecated. The performance hit of using scalar UDF in queries _can_ be devastating.

Answer (score 42):

One solution, offered by Jared Ko is to use **pseudo-constants**.

As explained in [SQL Server: Variables, Parameters or Literals? Or… Constants?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_appendix_z/2013/09/16/sql-server-variables-parameters-or-literals-or-constants/):

> Pseudo-Constants are not variables or parameters. Instead, they're simply views with one row, and enough columns to support your constants. With these simple rules, the SQL Engine completely ignores the value of the view but still builds an execution plan based on its value. The execution plan doesn't even show a join to the view!
>
> Create like this:
>
> ```sql
> CREATE SCHEMA ShipMethod
> GO
> -- Each view can only have one row.
> -- Create one column for each desired constant.
> -- Each column is restricted to a single value.
> CREATE VIEW ShipMethod.ShipMethodID AS
> SELECT CAST(1 AS INT) AS [XRQ - TRUCK GROUND]
>       ,CAST(2 AS INT) AS [ZY - EXPRESS]
>       ,CAST(3 AS INT) AS [OVERSEAS - DELUXE]
>       ,CAST(4 AS INT) AS [OVERNIGHT J-FAST]
>       ,CAST(5 AS INT) AS [CARGO TRANSPORT 5]
> ```
>
> Then use like this:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT h.*
> FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
> JOIN ShipMethod.ShipMethodID const
>     ON h.ShipMethodID = const.[OVERNIGHT J-FAST]
> ```
>
> Or like this:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT h.*
> FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
> WHERE h.ShipMethodID = (SELECT TOP 1 [OVERNIGHT J-FAST] FROM ShipMethod.ShipMethodID)
> ```

Comment: This is a MUCH better solution than the accepted answer.  Initially we went down the scalar function route and it has awful performance.  Much better is this answer and the link above to Jared Ko's article.

Comment: However, adding WITH SCHEMABINDING to a scalar function appears to improve its performance significantly.

Comment: The link is dead now.

Comment: @MatthieuCormier: I've updated the link, although it seems that MSDN had added a redirect from the old URL to the new one anyway.

Answer (score 32):

My workaround to missing constans is to give hints about the value to the optimizer.

```
DECLARE @Constant INT = 123;

SELECT * 
FROM [some_relation] 
WHERE [some_attribute] = @Constant
OPTION( OPTIMIZE FOR (@Constant = 123))
```

This tells the query compiler to treat the variable as if it was a constant when creating the execution plan. The down side is that you have to define the value twice.

Comment: It helps but it also defeats the purpose of a single definition.

Comment: I have found that `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` has the same effect as `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR ...)` - and then you don't have to specify the value twice. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40432794/989556). That makes this answer my preferred solution to this problem.

Answer (score 11):

No, but good old naming conventions should be used.

```
declare @MY_VALUE as int
```

Comment: @VictorYarema because sometimes convention is all you need. And because sometimes you have no other good choice. Now, that aside, SQLMenace's answer looks better, I'll agree with you. Even so, the functions name should follow the convention for constants, IMO. It should be named `FN_CONSTANT()`. That way it's clear what it's doing.

Comment: This alone won't help when you want the performance benefit. Try Michal D. and John Nilsson's answers for the performance boost as well.

Answer (score 8):

There is no built-in support for constants in T-SQL. You could use SQLMenace's approach to simulate it (though you can never be sure whether someone else has overwritten the function to return something else…), or possibly write a table containing constants, [as suggested over here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/simulating-constants-using-user-defined-functions). Perhaps write a trigger that rolls back any changes to the `ConstantValue` column?

Answer (score 7):

Prior to using a SQL function run the following script to see the differences in performance:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('fnFalse') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION fnFalse
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('fnTrue') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION fnTrue
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fnTrue() RETURNS INT WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 1
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fnFalse() RETURNS INT WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
RETURN ~ dbo.fnTrue()
END
GO

DECLARE @TimeStart DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @Count INT = 100000
WHILE @Count > 0 BEGIN
SET @Count -= 1

DECLARE @Value BIT
SELECT @Value = dbo.fnTrue()
IF @Value = 1
    SELECT @Value = dbo.fnFalse()
END
DECLARE @TimeEnd DATETIME = GETDATE()
PRINT CAST(DATEDIFF(ms, @TimeStart, @TimeEnd) AS VARCHAR) + ' elapsed, using function'
GO

DECLARE @TimeStart DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @Count INT = 100000
DECLARE @FALSE AS BIT = 0
DECLARE @TRUE AS BIT = ~ @FALSE

WHILE @Count > 0 BEGIN
SET @Count -= 1

DECLARE @Value BIT
SELECT @Value = @TRUE
IF @Value = 1
    SELECT @Value = @FALSE
END
DECLARE @TimeEnd DATETIME = GETDATE()
PRINT CAST(DATEDIFF(ms, @TimeStart, @TimeEnd) AS VARCHAR) + ' elapsed, using local variable'
GO

DECLARE @TimeStart DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @Count INT = 100000

WHILE @Count > 0 BEGIN
SET @Count -= 1

DECLARE @Value BIT
SELECT @Value = 1
IF @Value = 1
    SELECT @Value = 0
END
DECLARE @TimeEnd DATETIME = GETDATE()
PRINT CAST(DATEDIFF(ms, @TimeStart, @TimeEnd) AS VARCHAR) + ' elapsed, using hard coded values'
GO
```

Comment: This is quite old, but for reference here's the result when executed on my server: | `2760ms elapsed, using function` | 
`2300ms elapsed, using local variable` | 
`2286ms elapsed, using hard coded values` |

Comment: On a dev laptop, with two additional functions without schema binding. ```5570 elapsed, using function ``` | ```406 elapsed, using local variable``` | ```383 elapsed, using hard coded values``` |  ```3893 elapsed, using function without schemabinding```

Comment: For comparison, a simple select statement took 4110ms where the select statements alternated between ```select top 1 @m = cv_val from code_values where cv_id = 'C101' ``` and  same ```... 'C201' ``` where code_values is dictionary table with 250 vars, there were all on SQL-Server 2016

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in getting optimal execution plan for a value in the variable you can use a dynamic sql code. It makes the variable constant.

```
DECLARE @var varchar(100) = 'some text'
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = '''+@var+''''
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: This is how I do it and it gives a huge performance boost to queries that involve constants.

Answer (score 5):

For enums or simple constants, a view with a single row has great performance and compile time checking / dependency tracking ( cause its a column name )

See Jared Ko's blog post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_appendix_z/2013/09/16/sql-server-variables-parameters-or-literals-or-constants/

create the view

```
 CREATE VIEW ShipMethods AS
 SELECT CAST(1 AS INT) AS [XRQ - TRUCK GROUND]
   ,CAST(2 AS INT) AS [ZY - EXPRESS]
   ,CAST(3 AS INT) AS [OVERSEAS - DELUXE]
  , CAST(4 AS INT) AS [OVERNIGHT J-FAST]
   ,CAST(5 AS INT) AS [CARGO TRANSPORT 5]
```

use the view

```
SELECT h.*
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
WHERE ShipMethodID = ( select [OVERNIGHT J-FAST] from ShipMethods  )
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, lets see

Constants are immutable values which are known at compile time and do not change for the life of the program

that means you can never have a constant in SQL Server

```
declare @myvalue as int
set @myvalue = 5
set @myvalue = 10--oops we just changed it
```

the value just changed

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no build in support for constants, my solution is very simple.

Since this is not supported:

```
Declare Constant @supplement int = 240
SELECT price + @supplement
FROM   what_does_it_cost
```

I would simply convert it to

```
SELECT price + 240/*CONSTANT:supplement*/
FROM   what_does_it_cost
```

Obviously, this relies on the whole thing (the value without trailing space and the comment) to be unique. Changing it is possible with a global search and replace.

Comment: One problem is that it's available only locally

Answer (score 1):

SQLServer 2022 (currently only as Preview available) is now able to Inline the function proposed by SQLMenace, this should prevent the performance hit described by some comments.

`CREATE FUNCTION fnConstant() RETURNS INT AS BEGIN RETURN 2 END GO`

`SELECT is_inlineable FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE [object_id]=OBJECT_ID('dbo.fnConstant');`

| is_inlineable |
| --- |
| 1 |

`SELECT dbo.fnConstant()`

[ExecutionPlan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SMqo.png)

---

To test if it also uses the value coming from the Function, I added a second function returning value "1"

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnConstant1()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 1
END
GO
```

Create Temp Table with about 500k rows with Value 1 and 4 rows with Value 2:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp ;  
create table #temp (value_int INT)  
DECLARE @counter INT;  
SET @counter = 0  
WHILE @counter <= 500000  
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (1);  
    SET @counter = @counter +1  
END  
SET @counter = 0
  
WHILE @counter <= 3  
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (2);
    SET @counter = @counter +1
END
create index i_temp on #temp (value_int);
```

Using the describe plan we can see that the Optimizer expects 500k values for
`select * from #temp where value_int = dbo.fnConstant1(); --Returns 500001 rows`
[Constant 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDW4T.png)

and 4 rows for
`select * from #temp where value_int = dbo.fnConstant(); --Returns 4rows`
[Constant 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu8T3.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are no such thing as "creating a constant" in database literature. Constants exist as they are and often called values. One can declare a variable and assign a value (constant) to it. From a scholastic view:

```
DECLARE @two INT
SET @two = 2
```

Here @two is a variable and 2 is a value/constant.

Comment: Try Michal D. and John Nilsson's answers for a performance boost as well.

Comment: Literals are constant by definition. The ascii/unicode (depending on editor) character `2` gets translated into a binary value when assigned at "compile time". The actual value encoded depends on the data type it is being assigned to (int, char, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Robert's performance test is interesting. And even in late 2022, the scalar functions are much slower (by an order of magnitude) than variables or literals. A view (as suggested mbobka) is somewhere in-between when used for this same test.

That said, using a loop like that in SQL Server is not something I'd ever do, because I'd normally be operating on a whole set.

In SQL 2019, if you use schema-bound functions in a set operation, the difference is much less noticeable.

I created and populated a test table:

```sql
create table #testTable (id int identity(1, 1) primary key, value tinyint);
```

And changed the test so that instead of looping and changing a variable, it queries the test table and returns true or false depending on the value in the test table, e.g.:

```sql
insert @testTable(value)
select case when value > 127
    then @FALSE
    else @TRUE
end
from #testTable with(nolock)
```

I tested 5 scenarios:

1. hard-coded values
2. local variables
3. scalar functions
4. a view
5. a table-valued function

running the test 10 times, yielded the following results:

| scenario | min | max | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| scalar functions | 233 | 259 | 240 |
| hard-coded values | 236 | 265 | 243 |
| local variables | 235 | 278 | 245 |
| table-valued function | 243 | 272 | 253 |
| view | 244 | 267 | 254 |

Suggesting to me, that for set-based work in (at least) 2019 and better, there's not much in it.

```sql
set nocount on;
go

-- create test data table
drop table if exists #testTable;
create table #testTable (id int identity(1, 1) primary key, value tinyint);

-- populate test data
insert #testTable (value)
select top (1000000) convert(binary (1), newid()) 
from sys.all_objects a
    , sys.all_objects b
go

-- scalar function for True
drop function if exists fnTrue;
go
create function dbo.fnTrue() returns bit with schemabinding as
begin
    return 1
end
go

-- scalar function for False
drop function if exists fnFalse;
go
create function dbo.fnFalse () returns bit with schemabinding as
begin
    return 0
end
go

-- table-valued function for booleans
drop function if exists dbo.tvfBoolean;
go
create function tvfBoolean() returns table with schemabinding as
return
    select convert(bit, 1) as true, convert(bit, 0) as false
go

-- view for booleans
drop view if exists dbo.viewBoolean;
go
create view dbo.viewBoolean with schemabinding as
    select convert(bit, 1) as true, convert(bit, 0) as false
go

-- create table for results
drop table if exists #testResults
create table #testResults (id int identity(1,1), test int, elapsed bigint, message varchar(1000));

-- define tests
declare @tests table(testNumber int, description nvarchar(100), sql nvarchar(max))
insert @tests values 
  (1, N'hard-coded values', N'
declare @testTable table (id int, value bit);
insert @testTable(id, value)
select id, case when t.value > 127 
    then 0 
    else 1
end
from #testTable t')
, (2, N'local variables', N'
declare @FALSE as bit = 0
declare @TRUE as bit = 1
declare @testTable table (id int, value bit);
insert @testTable(id, value)
select id, case when t.value > 127 
    then @FALSE
    else @TRUE
end
from #testTable t'), 
(3, N'scalar functions', N'
declare @testTable table (id int, value bit);
insert @testTable(id, value)
select id, case when t.value > 127 
    then dbo.fnFalse()
    else dbo.fnTrue()
end
from #testTable t'), 
(4, N'view', N'
declare @testTable table (id int, value bit);
insert @testTable(id, value)
select id, case when value > 127
    then b.false
    else b.true
end
from #testTable t with(nolock), viewBoolean b'),
(5, N'table-valued function', N'
declare @testTable table (id int, value bit);
insert @testTable(id, value)
select id, case when value > 127
    then b.false
    else b.true
end
from #testTable with(nolock), dbo.tvfBoolean() b')
;

declare @testNumber int, @description varchar(100), @sql nvarchar(max)

declare @testRuns int = 10;

-- execute tests
while @testRuns > 0 begin
    set @testRuns -= 1

    declare testCursor cursor for select testNumber, description, sql from @tests;
    open testCursor

    fetch next from testCursor into @testNumber, @description, @sql
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
        
        declare @TimeStart datetime2(7) = sysdatetime();

        execute sp_executesql @sql;

        declare @TimeEnd datetime2(7) = sysdatetime()

        insert #testResults(test, elapsed, message) 
        select @testNumber, datediff_big(ms, @TimeStart, @TimeEnd), @description

        fetch next from testCursor into @testNumber, @description, @sql
    end 
    close testCursor
    deallocate testCursor
end


-- display results
select test, message, count(*) runs, min(elapsed) as min, max(elapsed) as max, avg(elapsed) as avg
from #testResults
group by test, message
order by avg(elapsed);
```

Answer (score -1):

The best answer is from SQLMenace according to the requirement if that is to create a temporary constant for use within scripts, i.e. across multiple GO statements/batches.

Just create the procedure in the tempdb then you have no impact on the target database.

One practical example of this is a database create script which writes a control value at the end of the script containing the logical schema version. At the top of the file are some comments with change history etc... But in practice most developers will forget to scroll down and update the schema version at the bottom of the file.

Using the above code allows a visible schema version constant to be defined at the top before the database script (copied from the generate scripts feature of SSMS) creates the database but used at the end. This is right in the face of the developer next to the change history and other comments, so they are very likely to update it.

For example:

```
use tempdb
go
create function dbo.MySchemaVersion()
returns int
as
begin
    return 123
end
go

use master
go

-- Big long database create script with multiple batches...
print 'Creating database schema version ' + CAST(tempdb.dbo.MySchemaVersion() as NVARCHAR) + '...'
go
-- ...
go
-- ...
go
use MyDatabase
go

-- Update schema version with constant at end (not normally possible as GO puts
-- local @variables out of scope)
insert MyConfigTable values ('SchemaVersion', tempdb.dbo.MySchemaVersion())
go

-- Clean-up
use tempdb
drop function MySchemaVersion
go
```