# What are the main differences between OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) and OPTION(RECOMPILE)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, parameter-sniffing

I run into the classic [Parameter Sniffing](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/11/06/what-is-parameter-sniffing/) issues in SQL Server 2012. Based on some research I found multiple options around this problem. The two options that I need to understand the difference between are `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` vs `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`.

I am hesitating to use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` at the end of my queries that are having this issue because it will force the server to generate a new execution plan each time. If I call this query often this will spike up the CPU of that machine.

So that I use he best available solution, what are the real differences between the two options?

Will `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` reuse cache instead of recompiling each time?

Comment: How complex are your queries?  You don't want to recompile queries in a transaction environment if you expect them to complete in a fraction of a second.  But if they are larger queries, then the overhead for the recompile is probably negligible compared to the actual execution.

Comment: My understanding is that `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` applies at the time the query is compiled. It tells the optimizer to ignore the specific parameter values and use its statistics to generate the plan. The resultant plan would be cached and not recompiled.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am not using it in a transaction. It is for a report that has to run often. It has about 10 left joins and 1 inner join. The query itself is not complicated.

Comment: @JohnD so is it fair to say the `OPTION(RECMPILE)` recompiled every time where `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` compiles once using UNKNOW? so `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` is cheaper in the case?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but that is my understanding, yes. However if the query plan is not very good for the particular cases that you will be using, you may be better off with the recompile option. Sometimes it's obvious from the query plan whether it works for you or not in your use cases. If not obvious, you can do benchmarks. Recompile option is expensive, but inefficient queries may be even more costly.

Answer (score 40):

> Will `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` reuse cache instead of recompiling
>   each time?

Yes, it will.

---

There are two main differences between `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` and `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` as can be seen from this quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx):

> `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`
>
> Instructs the query optimizer to use statistical
>   data instead of the initial values for all local variables when the
>   query is compiled and optimized, including parameters created with
>   forced parameterization.

> `RECOMPILE`
>
> Instructs the SQL Server Database Engine to discard the plan
>   generated for the query after it executes, forcing the query optimizer
>   to recompile a query plan the next time the same query is executed.
>   Without specifying `RECOMPILE`, the Database Engine caches query plans
>   and reuses them. When compiling query plans, the `RECOMPILE` query hint
>   uses the current values of any local variables in the query and, if
>   the query is inside a stored procedure, the current values passed to
>   any parameters.

So, the two main differences are:

1. Caching (or not) of the query plan.

Usually the generated query plan is cached and reused. `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` doesn't affect this feature of the engine. `RECOMPILE` suppresses this feature and tells the engine to discard the plan and not put it into the cache.

2. Using (or not) actual parameter values during plan generation.

Usually optimizer "sniffs" the parameter values and uses these values when generating the plan. `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` suppresses this feature and tells the engine to treat all parameters as if their values were unknown. Optimizer has built-in rules and heuristics how to use available statistics for various filtering criteria. See [Optimize for… Mediocre?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/optimize-for-unknown-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/) for more details. Normally parameter sniffing is used on the first run of the query/stored procedure and uses the values of parameters during the first run. The generated plan is cached and later can be reused.

One non-obvious thing to remember here is that in both cases (normal without any query hints and with `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` hint) the generated plan has to be valid and produce correct result for **any** possible parameter value. It is tailored to the sniffed values that were used during the first run in the normal/no-hint case; it is not tailored to any specific value in the `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` case, but it is still valid if parameter changes later in any way.

This is significant and it prevents optimizer from performing certain transformations and simplifications of the plan.

`OPTION(RECOMPILE)` allows optimizer to inline the actual values of parameters during each run and optimizer uses actual values of parameters to generate a better plan. It doesn't have to worry that the generated plan may not work with some other value of parameter, because the plan will not be cached and reused.

This effect is mostly visible for the [Dynamic Search Conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) queries. For example:

```
SELECT ...
FROM T
WHERE
    (@ParamSomeID = 0)
    OR
    (
        @ParamSomeID = -1
        AND
        T.SomeID NOT IN
        (
            SELECT OtherTable.SomeID
            FROM OtherTable
        )
    )
    OR
    (
        T.SomeID IN
        (
            SELECT OtherTable.SomeID
            FROM OtherTable
            WHERE OtherTable.SomeID = @ParamSomeID
        )
    )
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

If `@ParamSomeID` is `0` optimizer would treat the query as if it didn't have any `WHERE` clause at all. The plan would not mention `OtherTable` at all.

If `@ParamSomeID` is `-1`, the plan would join `T` to `OtherTable` using Left Anti Semi Join and would scan the whole `OtherTable`.

If `@ParamSomeID` is, say, 5, the plan would do an index seek in unique index on `OtherTable` and read only one row from `OtherTable`.

Without `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` this kind of simplification and transformation would not happen.

Another reason to use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` is when your data distribution is very skewed. For example, you have a table with 1M rows. One column has value 0 in 990K rows and values from 1 to 10 in 1K rows. The queries that filter on this column should have different plans depending on the actual value of the filter.

In both examples above `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` would generate a mediocre plan.

Answer (score 13):

> Will OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) reuse cache instead of recompiling each time?

Yes. Optimize for unknown will influence how the plan is generated (i.e. explicitly prevent it from sniffing parameters and compare it with column data histogram), but once generated the plan stays in cache and is reused.

`OPTION(RECOMPILE)` will force a recompile on every execution and is a rather heavy handed approach. It makes sense only in an analytical DW/BI environments where each query may be different, complex and probably with a significant run time.

You also have other options at your disposal:

- [Plan Guides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Query Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817826.aspx) (only in SQL 2016) as it allows you to 'pin' a favoured  execution plan

Both of these allow you to obtain the same effect as in your post, but in a non-invasive way (no app code/query changes).

Answer (score 8):

I have used both. `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` was used for a heavy search stored procedure that took in a variety of parameters. There were certain conditions, unknown to me (statistics and what not), that would throw the optimization off, the query was mundane, however, it would cause serious delays (and even time out). `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` solved this issue but was not ideal.

The same heavy search procedure would have intermittent issues, meaning after a few months, the search would time out. The immediate solution would be to call `sp_recompile` , which is synonymous to adding a `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` clause to the stored procedure.

The guts of the stored procedure propelled a **"result as you type"** solution in which every three keystrokes would trigger a DB search and the results would populate in a dropdown.

In the end, I removed the `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` and just simply added a `EXEC sp_recompile<sp>` to my nightly maintenance job and that resolved all issues.

Comment: Note: The `OPTION` can be applied to individual statements in the SP, all of which have their own plans/cache, which I often find more useful than adding it to the SP definition itself and allows greater flexibility (for a little bit more initial research on the source of the issue).

Comment: This is true and a good addition to the answer.

Comment: What was your reasoning *not* to keep both? Any reasons *against* that combination for such queries? (Self-optimizing during the day, clean recompile daily at night.)

Comment: Going back, the thought process at the time was that OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) would cause a recompile thousands and thousands of times a day, to avoid that, a nightly sp_recompile was added along with a monitor that would call sp_recompile when needed. If I could go back, I would probably accept the sub-second time trade-off, per call, as opposed to creating something to maintain the stability.  Now that caching is more commonplace than ever, there could be non rdms solutions that would provide extended benefits for similar type of data access needs.

Answer (score 0):

A down-side of `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKOWN)` is that it will use statistics to decide the best query plan during compilation.

If you have a query like:

```
WHERE (Posts.PostID = @PostID) OR (@PostID IS NULL)
```

The goal of the procedure is to allow the caller to either:

- operate of a specific `PostID`
- operate on *all* Posts

And the execution plan will be terrible when you pass `NULL`, because the query plan was optimized for a specific **value** of `PostID` that exists.

In those cases you *wish* `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` would optimize for unknown, rather than optimizing from a set of known values.

Comment: Wasn't that already mentioned here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40437749/861716

Comment: I don't believe so, no.